# Why did i get this result in php?

Tags: php

```
 if(NULL ==0){
             echo "test". NULL;//output is test
             echo "<br>";
             echo "test". 0;//output is test0

             }
```

If condition say both null and 0 are equal.But why did i get this result?

Answer (score 2):

You have used **Loose comparison** `==` . If you use **Strict comparison** `===` then you will find the differences.

Read more :

[`type comparison table`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

[`NULL in PHP`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php#language.types.null.syntax)

Answer (score 1):

Because it depends if you are looking at 0 as the number zero (as in nothing) or a string (as in the character '0').

Comment: If it was character `0`, it would have been `'0'`. `0` is the digit zero, not a string with one character 0.

Comment: Nope, Nick is correct, it's implicitly converted to character '0' once it goes into String operation.

Answer (score 1):

NULL in PHP has the following properties: 
NULL == NULL is true, 
NULL == FALSE is true. 
And in line with the relational model, NULL == TRUE fails

Over here you are comparing NULL to false whose output is true in PHP

Answer (score 1):

As Nick already said: in this case, you are adding the value `0` to a string that makes it also a string. That's why you get the value `test0`.

Also, in your `if`, you are checking for zero value, not a strict true or false statement:

```
<?php

if( NULL == 0 ) {
    echo "test" . NULL;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "test" . 0;
}

?>
```

Output:

```
test
test0
```

Now try it like this:

```
<?php

if( NULL === 0 ) {
    echo "test" . NULL;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "test" . 0;
}

?>
```

You will see, that you get no output, because now the `if` statement is false.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` has no value, in your comparison it is evaluating to False, and `0` is also evaluated as False (so False == False, which is True), which is why the body of the loop executes.

`NULL` explicitly means ***"no value"***. See [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) for what exactly `NULL` is.

Answer (score 0):

because if you concat a string with NOTHING (null) the string will remain at it is, if you concat with the integer "0", it will be casted to string (auto-boxing) and concated to the original string...

normal behaviour?

and "null == 0" -> true, but "null === 0" -> false...

you have to check not only the VALUE (which will be "zero" for both itc), you have to check TYPE equality too with "==="

Answer (score 0):

Because, a NULL string is nothing to be printed. Hence the first echo statement, concatenates:

```
"test" . NULL => "test" Then Nothing
```

While the 0 is a logical NULL, but in case of String it prints as 0.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, if you compare any value to a number, the value will be typecasted to Int or Float, and then the comparison will be done. In your case, the NULL is first typecasted to Int, which produces 0, and then compared, givng TRUE. Check [PHP type comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) and [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).